# How gcc multiple -o option works?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-options

I'm trying to understand how the **-o** option of gcc works, I know that it's used to specify the output file name, but what happen when I write something like this:

```
gcc main.c -o test0 -o test1
```

or

```
gcc main.c -o test0 -o test1 -o test2
```

?
I have noticed that: only the last one `-o <filename>` is taken into account.
So my question is: why I can specify multiple **-o** option? and how they can be useful ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options):

> `-o` *file*
>   Place output in file *file*. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
> If `-o` is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in **a.out**, the object file for *source.suffix* in *source***.o**, its assembler file in *source***.s**, a precompiled header file in *source.suffix***.gch**, and all preprocessed C source on standard output.

Playing around with it, it seems it is treated as a "global" option, allowed to specify only one output file, where only the last `-o` option given takes effect (as noted in the question).

```
$ gcc -c foo.c -o fooX.o bar.c -o barX.o
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.

$ gcc -c foo.c -o fooX.o -o fooY.o # produces fooY.o only
```

Overriding previous options if a former one conflicts is common for many command-line tools, which sometimes can be useful when writing scripts. As a (perhaps not so good) example, consider

```
alias gcc='gcc -o my_default' # a.out is a bad default name
```

in your **.bashrc**; you can still type

```
gcc -o foo foo.c
```

without getting an error. (The example is bad, because `gcc -c foo.c bar.c` is invalid now, but hopefully it gives an idea of how something like this *could* be helpful.)

Comment: Thanks very much, your example was what I was searching for.

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one output file, whose path is specified with the `-o` option.

Comment: So only the last -o is taken into account and the others are simply discarded ?

Comment: @LolloFake i see you have no accepted answers and I am afraid it's because you don't know about that, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @LolloFake and apparently now you will have to pick **mafso**'s answer, it's pretty detailed.

Comment: I thought it was an option for high reputation user, thanks for the info.